# Turning string into a list

Tags: python, arrays, list

I got stuck, so I have this input from a text file:

```
47 42 47 42 47 47 42
```

I'm trying to make it into a list with 7 elements, but my knowledge only goes as far as turning it into this:

```
['4', '7', ' ', '4', '2', ' ', '4', '7', ' ', '4', '2', ' ', '4', '7', ' ', '4', '7', ' ', '4', '2', '\n']
```

Instead of this:

```
[47, 42, 47, 42, 47, 47, 42]
```

**Thanks for any reply in forward!**

Comment: `list(map(int, "47 42 47 42 47 47 42".split()))`

Comment: use str `.split(' ')`  then int those.  result would look something like `[ int(splitstr) for splitstr in inputline.strip().split(' ') ]`

Comment: numbers_list = [ int(number) for number in text_file_input.split() ]